# Discord Python Rewrite - Giveaway Command in Cogs Error

Tags: python, discord.py

So, i was making a giveaway code in cogs, the code is:

```
import discord
import datetime
import time
import asyncio
import random
import random

from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Embed

class Giveaway(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def giveaway(self, ctx, time: int, *, prize):
        giveawayembed = discord.Embed(
            title=" New Giveaway! ",
            colour=discord.Color.green()
            )

        giveawayembed.add_field(name="Prize", value="{}".format(prize), inline=False)
        giveawayembed.add_field(name="Hosted by", value=f"{ctx.author.mention}", inline=False)
        giveawayembed.add_field(name="Ends in", value="{}s".format(time))

        msg = await ctx.send(embed=giveawayembed)

        reactions = await msg.add_reaction("")

        await asyncio.sleep(time)

        async for users in reactions.users(0):
            users = await reaction.users().flatten()
            winner = random.choice(users)

        endembed = discord.Embed(
            title="Giveaway ended!",
            description="Prize: {}\nWinner: {}".format(prize, winner))

        await msg.edit(embed=endembed)

    @giveaway.error
    async def giveaway_error(self, ctx, error):
        await ctx.send(error)
        print(error)
        raise error

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Giveaway(client))
```

but when i tried it, in works, but getting the winner had some errors
The error:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'users'

Answer (score 1):

The [`message.add_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction) coroutine does not return anything, which means `reactions = await msg.add_reaction("")` will result in `reactions` being `None`.

The below code will refresh the `message` object and overwrite `msg`, as this is needed to get the new reactions on the message.

It will also check if a winner was selected (in case no one entered the giveaway) and will remove the bot account from being able to win the giveaway.

```
import discord
import datetime
import time
import asyncio
import random

from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Embed

class Giveaway(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def giveaway(self, ctx, time: int, *, prize):
        giveawayembed = discord.Embed(
            title=" New Giveaway! ",
            colour=discord.Color.green()
            )

        giveawayembed.add_field(name="Prize", value="{}".format(prize), inline=False)
        giveawayembed.add_field(name="Hosted by", value=f"{ctx.author.mention}", inline=False)
        giveawayembed.add_field(name="Ends in", value="{}s".format(time))

        msg = await ctx.send(embed=giveawayembed)

        await msg.add_reaction("")

        await asyncio.sleep(time)

        msg = await msg.channel.fetch_message(msg.id)
        winner = None
        
        for reaction in msg.reactions:
            if reaction.emoji == "":
                users = await reaction.users().flatten()
                users.remove(self.client.user)
                winner = random.choice(users)

        if winner is not None:
            endembed = discord.Embed(
                title="Giveaway ended!",
                description="Prize: {}\nWinner: {}".format(prize, winner))

            await msg.edit(embed=endembed)

    @giveaway.error
    async def giveaway_error(self, ctx, error):
        await ctx.send(error)
        print(error)
        raise error

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Giveaway(client))
```

Comment: Hey, I'll try that code tomorrow because it's late at night right now, thank's for the awnser!